# Get file name only from a given path

Tags: powershell

I have a file which will have full path of files. For example:

```
servername\xyz\abc.txt
servername\pqr\ab1.txt
```

I need to get only file name (`abc.txt` and `ab1.txt`) using PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the resources getting the file you can use `Split-Path` on each line item. `-Leaf` is the switch needed to return just the file name.

```
PS M:\Scripts> split-path "servername\pqr\ab1.txt" -Leaf
ab1.txt
```

If you had this information in a file you could iterate through all the entires

```
$fileName = Get-Content fullfilepaths.txt | ForEach-Object{split-path $_ -Leaf}
```

**Another**

A simple one that would also work ( Not sure if the performance is different ) would be to use `split` and return the last element.

```
("servername\pqr\ab1.txt".Split("\"))[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. PSH$ $file = Get-ChildItem "servername\pqr\ab1.txt"
2. PSH$ $file.Name

PSH$ $file.Name 
should return ab1.txt